# Insert latest records efficiently in hive

Tags: hive, hql

I have around 90 tables in hive, 10 each are combined using union all in to 9 master tables.

These 90 base tables are inserted with new rows every 15 minutes. We need to bring in the newly inserted rows in master tables every 15 minutes.

Checking the ID with "not in" is consuming some time.

I have time stamps column as well, getting data based on that as well taking time

Is there a efficient way of achieving this. " Inserting newly added records in base tables into master every 15 minutes"

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

Option 1 - You can create a new table to keep max date timestamp for each master,stage combination. Table should be like this

```
masters,stages, mxts
master1,stage1, 2021-01-01 12:30:30
...
```

Then use it in sql like similar to above sql.

```
select * from Staging table-1 s 
Join maxtimestamp On timestamp > mxts and stages='stage1' and masters='master1'
union all
select * from Staging table-2 s 
Join maxtimestamp On timestamp > mxts and stages='stage2'and masters='master1'
```

And then insert max timespamp into the new table everyday after load.

Option 2 - if you can add a new column to master table called record_created_by to keep a track which stage is creating the data.
And your insert statement would be like this

```
select s.*, 'master1~stage1' as record_created_by from Staging table-1 s 
Join (select max(timestamp) mxts from master where record_created_by='master1~stage1') mx On timestamp > mxts
union all
select s.*, 'master1~stage2' as record_created_by from Staging table-2 s 
Join (select max(timestamp) mxts from master where record_created_by='master1~stage2') mx On timestamp > mxts
```

Pls note your first time insert statement would be same above sql but without timestamp part. If you have multiple stages, you can add them like this sql.

First option is way faster but you need to create and maintain a new table.

Comment: Yeah I  was also thinking of the first option, implemented it. For now with the amount of data. "Not in" is slightly faster than intermediate table with join. Current data is thousands

Comment: sounds good. i am glad my answer helped :)